# Automatic Windows lock at given time

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I'm looking for a software for Windows XP or a mechanism within Windows XP that will allow me to automatically lock Windows (same effect as WinKey + L) at a given time (e.g. at 3:30 pm) or after certain timer expires (e.g. 15 minutes).

I'm going to take an interview and the interviewee will be assigned fixed amount of time to solve some programming problems with PC. I like the PC to be locked after that time has elapsed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While logged in as an administrator, open a command prompt. Use the `at` command to create a scheduled task to lock the computer. The command to lock the computer is `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation`.

For example, `at 13:56 /next:monday "rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation"` would cause the workstation to lock at 1:56 PM next Monday.

If you don't have administrative access needed for the `at` command, you can add a scheduled task in the control panel to do the same thing.

Comment: unfortunately i'm not the admin of the pc. this seems doesn't work at non-admin pc.

Comment: `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation` should work as a non-admin but `at` won't. So, why not try sticking `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation` in to a scheduled task via Control Panel - users can create tasks local to thier account without needing admin rights.

Comment: Ah, I had assumed you had admin access, so I didn't originally include the control panel method in my answer. Updated the answer; thanks @DMA57361.

Comment: For some unknown reason I cannot set a scheduled task to lock the workstation. Here is what I've put into the Run field of advanced property of the scheduled task: `"C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation"`. I've also provided username and password. What am I missing?

Comment: You put the quotes in the wrong place. You need quotes around the path, but not around the arguments. It should be `"C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe" user32.dll, LockWorkStation`. Right now you're trying to run a file named "rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation" in the system32 folder; you want to run the rundll32.exe file with the arguments `user32.dll, LockWorkStation`. Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

The Windows command line tool has a command called "SHUTDOWN" which on Windows 7 at least has the option to log off rather than shutting down the computer. Fortunately it seems this is also in Windows XP!

[Shutdown command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shutdown.mspx?mfr=true)

You would need to have something schedule the machine to shut down after 15 minutes, I would not recommend using the Windows Scheduler or the command line "AT" command as in my experience these are unreliable.

If you have any programming skills then create a simple program which determines when 15 minutes have passed and issues the command line SHUTDOWN command.

Comment: Why the scheduler will be less reliable than self-written application?

Comment: force logging off seems aggressive. the interviewee may not save his/her last edit.

Comment: @whitequark in my experience the Windows Scheduler works until it doesn't, in my opinion based on years of experience it isn't reliable.

@Donotalo surely you would only want to employ people who are capable of managing their time effectively to not still be working when the end of the 15 minutes time is up? 8-)

Comment: The `shutdown` command has a timeout switch, hasn't it?

Comment: Agree with @Donatalo but want to make it clear that Locking and Logging Off are totally different things

Answer (score 1):

There's a shareware that can achieve this: [Desktop Lock 7.2](http://www.toplang.com/desktoplock.htm).

> You can let it automatically lock your
>   computer at any time you specified.
>   (Schedule)